# Is there a safe way to follow a suspicious link?

Tags: email, spam

When I get suspicious emails, I pretty much always just report it as spam, delete forever, and then be done with them. Low quality spam is pretty easy to identify, but sometimes they are on the boundary enough to make me unsure if they're legitimate or not. These are usually repeat marketing-type emails that have an unsubscribe link near the bottom, and the URL even contains "=unsub" in the text. This makes it hard to tell the difference between really poor-quality marketing and smart spammers. If there's the option to unsubscribe from marketing so I never get the emails that would be preferred, but I'm suspicious enough to know there's a high risk if I click the link. Is there any safe way to follow the link and investigate further?

Comment: I guess you could scan the link on VirusTotal, just remember to remove the unsub part, otherwise the antivirus scanner visits the webpage you might be unsubscribed from something you wanted to be subbed to :p

Comment: There are a few companies that offer "browser isolation" - a browser instance running on their servers that you access using application remoting.

Comment: Right-click on the link to copy/paste, then look at it first in a text editor, and then also paste it into a Punicode converter to reveal a homograph attack (if the converted link looks any different from the original, it contains non-English letters that look like English ones, i.e. homographs, which could be an indication of an attack)